# How to change Simple Marker to SVG Marker?

Tags: pyqgis, line, markers, svg

I have a line type layer and I want to add an svg type marker, I managed to add a simple marker to the layer's symbology according to the image, with the attached code. Is it possible to change this simple marker with an svg icon?

```
layerName = 'rede_bombas'
vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]
ggsl = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
ggsl.setSymbolType(QgsSymbol.Marker)
ggsl.setGeometryExpression("centroid($geometry)")
ggsl.setColor(QColor('Blue'))
symbol = vLayer.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())[0]
symbol.insertSymbolLayer(1, ggsl)
vLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, but if anyone has a better solution.

```
path = r"C:\Users\Aloísio\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\QWater\icons\qwater.svg"
layerName = 'rede_bombas'
vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)[0]

symbol_svg = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer(path)
symbol_svg.setSize(6)
symbol_svg.setFillColor(QColor('#0000ff'))
symbol_svg.setStrokeColor(QColor('#ff0000'))
symbol_svg.setStrokeWidth(1)

marker_symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol()
marker_symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_svg)

ggsl = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
ggsl.setSubSymbol(marker_symbol)
ggsl.setGeometryExpression("centroid($geometry)")

symbol = vLayer.renderer().symbols(QgsRenderContext())[0]
symbol.insertSymbolLayer(1, ggsl)
vLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]